# How to get Windows' "Start" icon from window handle

Tags: c#, windows, icons

I used the following advice to obtain icons for various running apps based on their respective window handles:

[Find an application’s icon with WinAPI](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/12/18/find-an-applications-icon-with-winapi/)

Unfortunately, it doesn't get the icon for processes belonging to the "Start" button.  How can I get the "Start" button's icon?

Comment: Whatever you are planning to do with that, don't do it on Windows 8 ;)

Comment: The start button is a bitmap, not an icon.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean "icon" in a programmatic object sense.  If you can explain how to retrieve the bitmap that works for me.

Comment: @HansPassant Windows 8 is not even in the picture!

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening %systemroot%/system32/shell32 (Open visual studio, open file, go to c:/windows/system32/shell32, then it lists a file tree, check icons, then find your icon. althought it doesn't give a name but there's lots of icons there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the Windows version. Most of the resources are tucked away in the theme assemblies. Explorer.exe "owns" the taskbar and the start button, but its not in there where it gets it from.